# Symfony-Twig TypeAhead Function

Tags: php, symfony, twig, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement the typeAhead Function. I am using the Symfony framework. But if doesnt seems to work. 
The Error Im getting is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined

I am very new to symfony and twig. Can someone point me out the why the code isnt working?

**Twig**

```html
<div id="prefetch">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Countries">
</div>
```

```js
<script type="application/javascript">
    var countries = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        // url points to a json file that contains an array of country names, see
        // https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/gh-pages/data/countries.json
        prefetch: '{{ path('typeAhead') }}'
    });

    // passing in `null` for the `options` arguments will result in the default
    // options being used
    $('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'countries',
        source: countries
    });
</script>
```

**Controller (Response)**

```
/**
 * @Route("/typeAhead", name="typeAhead")
 */
public function typeAheadAllAction(Request $request)
{
    $products=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(products::class)->findAll();

    $pr_name=array();
    foreach($products as $product){
        $name=$product->getName();
        array_push($pr_name,$name);
    }

    return new Response(json_encode(array($pr_name)),100);
}
```

**Controller (rendering the twig file)**

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")
 */
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('typeahead.html.twig', array(
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Maybe you are pointing to [this example page](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/), and you want to implement Bloodhood (typeAhead's suggestion engine).

If so, please consider adding `typeahead.bundle.js` which has both typeAhead & Bloodhood (you may inspect the page and see the link there below jQuery):

```
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for the warm Welcome. It worked! Thank you soo much for the kind help :)